# Why does type inference doesn't give consistence results with generics in the following case?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

So, we've a function `foo` that does not specify any type for `this`, which means `this` parameter for `foo` is `unknown` (`ThisParameterType<typeof foo>`).

Next, we have a `wrapper` function that accepts two arguments and **there's a generic type argument `T` that's used at three places.**

Now, when we call `wrapper` with `foo` and a `string`, `T` is `unknown` for the `this` parameter but is a `string` for the `arg0` parameter, but the **final inference for `T` is `string`.**

```
function foo() {}

function wrapper<T>(_cb: (this: T, ...args: any[]) => any, _arg0: T): T {
  return "" as any as T;
}

let bar = "bar"
wrapper(foo, bar)
```

Let's now see a similar example, where it behaves differently. Here also `T` is `unknown` at one place and `number` at another, **but the resultant inference this time is `unknown` and not `number`.**

```
function someFunc<T>(a: T, b: T): [T, T] {
  return [a, b];
}

let num = 10
someFunc(num as unknown, num);
```

I want to understand the reason behind this inconsistency?

**Update based on jcalz comment:**

> Another is that `ThisParameterType<T>` is defined to return `unknown` if there is no `this` parameter, which does not mean that this is `unknown`;

Agreed and to verify what `this` actually get's inferred when it's not explicitly defined, I created the example below and if you notice you'll see that `T` is inferred as `unknown`, which means it aligns with how `ThisParameterType` behaves. I just mentioned `ThisParameterType` because adding this example would have made the question unnecessarily complicated.

```
function foo() { }

function wrapper<T>(cb: (this: T) => void) { }

wrapper(foo)
```

Comment: There are a number of things interacting in this particular pair of examples that muddles the situation.  One is that TypeScript doesn't have a `--strictThis` flag (see [ms/TS#7968](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7968)) so a function like `foo()` with no explicit `this` parameter will be compatible with, say, `(this: string)=>void` even though it shouldn't be.  If you explicitly mark it as `foo(this: void)` then you'll get errors.  Another is that `ThisParameterType<T>` is defined to return `unknown` if there is no `this` parameter, which does *not* mean that `this` is `unknown`; ...

Comment: ... so there is not an `unknown` in an inference site for `T`.  There's only `string`.  So `string` is inferred.  If you explicitly mark `foo(this: unknown)` then the reason `string` is inferred has to do with the inference site being [contravariant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66410115/2887218). For your second question you have both `unknown` and `number` appearing in covariant inference sites, and since `unknown` is a supertype of `number` the compiler infers `unknown` (since a supertype matches both and a subtype does not).

Comment: Do those explanations make sense and fully address the question?  If so I could write up an answer with sources.  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: I think saying "so there is not an unknown in an inference site for T" is not correct. I've updated my question, and the example shows that TS infers `unknown` if `this` is not explicitly defined, so why wouldn't it do that here? Which also means that both the scenarios with and without `this` explicitly defined results into `string` because of "contravarience", which I'll have to learn more about.

Comment: To make this easier to discuss, would it be okay to define `foo` like `function foo(this:unknown) { }`?  Then things behave similarly and there is definitely `unknown` to infer, as opposed to just falling back to the implicit constraint.  Otherwise the question seemingly is about the lack of strict `this` parameter behavior and whether or not there's a "real" `unknown` there and it seems to be a distraction from what you really want to know.  Indeed we could remove the dependence on the `this` parameter entirely and switch it to a regular parameter like [so](https://tsplay.dev/WkKRjW).

Comment: Which shows the same variance issue, and I'd be happy to explain that.  How do you want to proceed?

Comment: Yeah, that's better, let's not worry what `this` is being inferred as. And, it'd be really helpful if you could proceed with the explanation.

Comment: Okay I'm in the middle of writing up an answer but Stack Overflow seems to be unstable right now.  I might have to finish later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's look at the simple case:

```
let num = 10
let unk: unknown = num

function f<T>(a: T, b: T) { }
f(unk, num);
// function f<unknown>(a: unknown, b: unknown): void
```

In the call to `f()`, the type checker needs to infer the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `T` from the types of values you've passed in for `a` and `b`.  Another way of saying this is that the appearances of `T` in the `a` type and the `b` type are *inference sites*.

You have one value of [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown), TypeScript's [top type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_type), and one value of [the primitive `number` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#the-primitives-string-number-and-boolean) corresponding to just numbers.  So there are two candidates from which it can choose.

What happens if it chooses `number`?  Well that wouldn't work because while `num` is of type `number`, `unk` is *not* (even though we know it's actually a `number` at runtime, we've intentionally widened `unk` to the `unknown` type).  Since `unknown` is not assignable to `number`, that inference would fail to type check.

What happens if it chooses `unknown`?  That works just fine because `unk` is already of type `unknown`, and `num` can *also* be treated as having type `unknown`.  Indeed, the whole point of the top type `unknown` is that all types are assignable to it.

And so the compiler chooses `unknown`.

---

Now compare to the following variation:

```
function unkFunc(x: unknown) { }
function numFunc(x: number) { x.toFixed() }

function g<T>(a: (x: T) => void, b: (x: T) => void) { }
g(unkFunc, numFunc)
// function g<number>(a: (x: number) => void, b: (x: number) => void): void
```

In the call to `g()`, the appearances of `T` in the types of `a` and `b` are still inference sites, but now they appear in positions of a function parameter.  Again you have one value where `T` should be inferred as `unknown` and another where `T` should be inferred as `number`. So there are two candidates.

What happens if the compiler chooses `unknown`?  That *wouldn't work* because while `unkFunc` is definitely of type `(x: unknown) => void`, `numFunc` is *not* of type `(x: unknown) => void`.  If it were, you could call it with any value you want, like `numFunc("")` or `numFunc({})` or `numFunc(null)`.  If you actually do any of those you'll get a runtime error, and even if you didn't (if I left out the `x.toFixed()` line), it would be wrong because `numFunc`'s call signature requires that its parameter be of type `number`.  And since `unknown` is not assignable to `number`, that inference would fail to type check.
assignable to `number`, that inference would fail to type check.

What happens if it chooses `number`?  That works just fine because `numFunc` is already of type `(x: number) => void`, and `unkFunc` can *also* be treated as having type `(x: number) => void`.  It is perfectly safe to treat a function that accepts anything as one that only accepts numbers. The call `unkFunc(10)` is fine.

And so the compiler chooses `number`.

Note how the direction of inference and type checking for function parameters is opposite to that of plain values.  In other words, `((x: A) => void) extends` ((x: B) => void)`if and only if`B extends A`.  The type of a function varies *counter* to the type of its parameter.  In other words, functions are **contravariant** in their parameter types.  The inference sites in` g()`are in "contravariant positions", whereas those in`f()` are in **covariant** positions (because they vary the same way as the type you're trying to measure... they co-vary).

See [Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance and Bivariance in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66410115/2887218) and [the Wikipedia entry on variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) for a general discussion about variance, and the [release notes for `--strictFunctionTypes`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types) which also discusses contravariance of function parameters.

---

Your `foo()` example is essentially this, although there are some details that make it harder to see.  One detail is that one inference site is contravariant and the other is covariant.  That means it would turn out to be fine no matter which of `number` or `unknown` gets inferred:

```
function h<T>(a: (x: T) => void, b: T) { }
h<number>(unkFunc, num); // okay
h<unknown>(unkFunc, num); // okay
```

Of course when you actually call it, you get `number` and not `unknown`, and you still might want to know why:

```
h(unkFunc, num); 
// function h<number>(a: (x: number) => void, b: number): void
```

That's because inference sites have different **priority** (see [ms/TS#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829) for a related issue in which inference site priority is discussed).  Roughly speaking, because `(x: T) => void` is a more complex type than `T`, the compiler gives more priority to the simpler inference site.  So  will tend to infer from `b` and not from `a`.  Since the `number` candidate from `b` works, that's what you get.

Another detail is that you're using a virtual [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-parameters) instead of a regular parameter, but functions are still contravariant in their `this` context:

```
function unkThisFunc(this: unknown) { }
function i<T>(a: (this: T)=>void, b: T) {}
i(unkThisFunc, num);
// function i<number>(a: (this: number) => void, b: number): void
i<number>(unkThisFunc, num); // okay
i<unknown>(unkThisFunc, num); // okay
```

And thirdly you are not actually specifying the `this` parameter, and it gets tricky to say whether we should treat this as being implicitly `unknown` or whether there isn't actually a candidate present for that inference site, which would end up falling back to the implicit `unknown` generic [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints), but again, you get the same behavior:

```
function implicitUnkThisFunc() { }
i(implicitUnkThisFunc, num);
//function i<number>(a: (this: number) => void, b: number): void
i<number>(implicitUnkThisFunc, num); // okay
i<unknown>(implicitUnkThisFunc, num); // okay
```

But backing way up, I think the important bit to understand here is that you can assign `number` to `unknown` but not vice versa, and you can  assign `(x: unknown) => void` to `(x: number) => void` but not vice versa.  Armed with that, it makes sense that `number` is a valid inference candidate when the parameter type is `unknown`.  You might still wonder why `number` is chosen over `unknown`, but the fact that `number` is valid should no longer be a concern.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAdgrgthAvBAjABgFCkjKBrALglzygHsB3KJaeDAM1wGMwBLM6+gHgBUA+ABQBDIjwA0EAEaiAlBADeEAL4MBJCbDgyA3BgD0eiIygt2nLiXJVBI4vitQJ0u6UpQZRAG5lWAEwwBxqYcLgBizAIAHkSWbnKKKkFsIZrhJlFEmpIgAE7xEJEAdGBkoayRIL4CconMydQA5rw2RBkQPHKIfBDefk6t0e2d3b2++SoNavhpTBrwMzL6hklmEE1ZuS0QbRt5SCM+vv3bg7vDPYceF36BdasAFs3CA7L710dSrwkY91N4M3MtLoDEY7iFHrstjt4Nk9l13sczl5Dj8uJC-gDaECICCyHghABPVGxawY5iAnQ4wx4wm3Ez1Fw8e6sADOMwEYGZLJi9jiCmUDDB1FYT1sHK5r3ho2OHX5KlYfyZrMxmh0S1B9NWIvRYs5rMyMNy52lnyxsKuoww2sNOUEJCVbPJWMpuPxRJFJKgdvwDpV8Bd1LddOCwrgAAdgKwmKwwABVH1c9njK0CVjhyPRuMJ5VO1XAvQrELWuCwqF67lmo1vE3OJHvK1om2CNMRqMx+N4X25-3aKkQGnuiy80ktjPt7OOkwU3uu2kYIA))

Comment: Beautifully explained, all of this makes so much sense now! Thanks :)

Comment: One more request, there's another really interesting recently asked TS question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73669925/why-does-adding-a-constraint-on-a-generic-type-change-the-inference-behavior), can you please take a look at that, I'm unable to understand how TS decides when to widen and narrow a generic type argument. There's already an answer but it's not that detailed.

Comment: The answer there looks right to me... `T extends string` has a constraint including the `string` primitive type, so the compiler sees it as a hint not to widen the string literal type, whereas unconstrained `T` doesn't, so it is widened.  It's mostly written out in [ms/TS#10676](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676)